# How to enable Sign in with Apple on my Firebase website

Tags: angular, firebase, google-cloud-platform, apple-sign-in

I am trying to enable Sign in with Apple on my Firebase website.

The documentation is just not there. I have followed the Google link:

https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/apple?authuser=0&hl=en

...and the Apple link:

https://developer.apple.com/help/account/configure-app-capabilities/about-sign-in-with-apple

So it seems I need to create a Service ID in Apple Developer. Here's what I did:

1. Visited Certificates, Identifiers & Profiles
2. Clicked "Identifiers"
3. Clicked "+"
4. Selected "Service IDs"
5. Entered a Description and an Identifier
6. Checked "Sign in with Apple" and clicked "Configure"

At this point, there is a greyed-out message: "No App ID is available"

7. Entered my domain in "Domains and Subdomains"
8. Entered my Firebase auth callback in "Return URLs"

The "Done" button mentioned in the dialog's instructions does not exist, and the "Next" button is greyed-out.

## EDIT

So it seems I had to create an App ID, which I did.

So I think I got it all configured to the best of my understanding, but the auth in my Angular app is not doing anything. It redirects to Firebase Auth but then just comes back immediately without having done anything:

```
import {
  Auth,
  authState,
  GoogleAuthProvider,
  signOut,
  signInWithPopup,
  User,
  signInWithRedirect, getRedirectResult, getAuth
} from '@angular/fire/auth';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AuthService {
  public readonly user: Observable<User | null> = EMPTY;
  public isLoggedIn: Observable<boolean> | undefined;

  constructor(@Optional() private auth: Auth, private router: Router) {
    if (auth) {
      this.user = authState(this.auth);
      this.isLoggedIn = authState(this.auth).pipe(
        traceUntilFirst('auth'),
        map(u => !!u)
      )
    }
  }

  async appleAuth() {
    if (this.auth) {
      const provider = new OAuthProvider('apple.com');
      const auth = firebase.getAuth();
      await signInWithRedirect(auth, provider);
      return firstValueFrom(this.isLoggedIn!);
    }

    return false;
  }
  
  // ...other methods

}
```

Google sign in, which follows the same pattern, works absolutely fine.

I have also tried using the imports from "fire/auth" directly as described on [this page](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/apple?hl=en&authuser=0&_gl=1*1uqpbs6*_ga*NjU4MTUyMzE5LjE2ODg0MDAwODE.*_ga_CW55HF8NVT*MTY4ODg0MDMzNy43LjAuMTY4ODg0MDMzNy4wLjAuMA..).

Any ideas?

I receive the error:

> FirebaseError: Firebase: Error (auth/operation-not-allowed).

One fly in the ointment might be that I am using my own domain's callback URL, although Firebase tells me that I need to add theirs to Developer portal. I have done that too, but it might be interfering? I must use my own, otherwise Google won't work.